# Deleting old entries in Elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

At different random times throughout the day I am going to do a "crawl" of data which I am going to feed into Elasticsearch. This bit is working just fine.

However the index should reflect only what was found in my most recent crawl and I currently have nothing to remove the content in the Elasticsearch index which was left over from the previous crawl but wasn't found in the new crawl.

From what I can see I have a few options:

A) Delete items based on how old they are. Won't work because index times are random.

B) Delete entire index and feed with fresh data. Doesn't seem very efficient and will leave me time with an empty or partial index.

C) Do an insert/modify query, if not found insert, if found already in the index update the timestamp, then do a second pass to delete any items with an older time stamp.

D) Something better.

What is a logical and efficient way to removing old content in a situation like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, and you are sure that each crawl contains the complete data set, I would do this:

- Crawl into time based index: you index-201504051656
- In one go:

  - Create an alias to that new created index
  - Remove alias from previous index
- close the old index or delete the old index

That way your application can always talk to the alias and you are sure that you will always have an index to talk to. Removing a lot of records from an index is relative heavy, closing or removing an index is relative cheap.